# Private github repo with "Free" account collaborators : are content, forks, etc. guaranteed private?

Tags: github

Say I have a private repo R1, and I invite some collaborators who have "free" accounts.

When those collaborators make changes, create a fork of my repo, edit it, make pull requests to the original private repo, etc., are all the contents (including forks) completely invisible to the public?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but how the interface/accounts work) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any changes done by the collaborators of a private repo are invisible to the public (both free or paid). And forks of existing private repositories will remain private and do not count towards your private repositories.

Source & for more info: https://github.com/plans